# Call custom product list instead of base

Tags: layout, product-list, xml

I want to call my custom `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mytheme/catalog/product/list.phtml file` instead of `base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

The list.phtml file is same as in base, but i have added some conditions for price.

I have my custom XML file at `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/mycustom.xml`

I have used below code in my xml but no luck and is still calling the `list.phtml file from base`

```
<catalog_category_default>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" />
            </reference>
```

How can I do this using XML ?

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that using a XML file. You should configure your theme from Configuration - Design or from System - Configuration - General - Design.
Here is a [full guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes#head-how-to-assign-a-theme) to achieve that.

Comment: I am working a custom extension whereby if the extensino is enabled then `base/list.phtml` will be replaced by my `list.phtml`

Comment: There is no real need to create an extension, the theming in Magento is flexible enough to have your particular case considered.

Comment: I want to replace by list.phtml instead of base's. Do I need to put that file under `base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` ?

Comment: That is one of the bad practices we try to avoid. Any change in the base theme will be overwritten in any Magento update. Use the guide i sent you to achieve this.

Comment: But I am not using any theme to configure. Its just an extension which replaces list.phtml with my custom code. Do I really have to configure theme for the same ?

Comment: You don't have to do anything you don't want. This is the way to achieve what you are looking for and be sure that this change will not be overwritten in the future while updating Magento. The rest is up to you.

Comment: Knowing the standards and providing the solution - both are different

Comment: Nope. What you are trying to do is wrong from the Magento perspective based on the standards and good practices. This way of resolving issues will give you no sleep in the near future. Plain and simple.

Comment: So without configuring any theme, how could I achieve the same ?